# How would I check email using gmail atom and Lua Socket?

Tags: lua, luasocket, moonscript

I've had this working before, but I think whatever it is doing for IPV6 support now is breaking it. I'm not sure though.

```
require "socket"
require "socket.http"

url = "https://username:password@gmail.google.com/­gmail/­feed/­atom"

print socket.http.request url
```

Results in

```
moon: C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\http.lua:116: bad argument #2 to 'connect' (number expected, got string)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'request'
        test.moon:6: (4) in main chunk
```

Comment: Please test all  your configurations, find a working one, then tell us what differs between the working one and the broken one.

Comment: Sorry to mislead you, my functional setup was ages ago and the code is long gone.

As far as I can recall, the code was functionally identical and the format of the http request didn't change at all - I suspect a change in Lua Socket is to blame.